# Capturar solo el valor de una variable pero no el tipo de dato

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una variable tipo $scope, a la que le asigno un string así:

```
$scope.visitasEnConjuntoSel.municipio = "San Antonio";
```

Cuando le realizo un console.log me muestra el valor que le estoy asignando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando inspecciono el elemento que usa la variable $scope me muestra en el value el tipo de dato y el valor, yo necesito que me llegue solo el valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo suprimir lo que esta resaltado en amarillo?

Comment: Hola, [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783294/angular-adds-strange-options-into-select-element-when-setting-model-value) respuesta esta en ingles, pero el problema es exactamente que el tuyo, hechale un vistazo, puede que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias! @Pablo Lozano Ahí encontré mucho de como orientar la solución.